# How to prove d-separation implies conditional independence?

Tags: bayesian-network, causality, causal-diagrams

All of the materials I see online just state it as fact. I don't see it as obvious at all.

I use this definition of a Belief network.
[image]

And this is the definition of d-seperation from the textbook:

[image]